# s3cmd copy removes metadata, how do you maintain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am using the Website Redirect Location feature of S3s web hosting. The architecture uses a bucket for the production www (www) site, and a bucket (redirects) for legacy 301 redirects that have been recreated as directories+files in S3, then metadata has been set for the redirects per AWS documentation.

I am using the s3cmd to copy the contents of redirects into www, but the metadata is being stripped.

This is the command:

```
s3cmd cp -r s3://redirects/ s3://www/
```

- of course my bucket names have been shortened for this question

If there is another way to migrate 301 redirects from .htaccess into S3, please enlighten me :)

Comment: Apache bench with 100K requests / DDoS to S3-stored static website makes your bill surprisingly high, double think before do that.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - not an issue in this situation. In terms of cost savings... its $20k in yearly fees for EC2 instances vs $3+k for S3.

Comment: not sure about $20k, http://www.ec2instances.info Do you really need *Cluster GPU Quadruple Extra Large cg1.4xlarge 22.5 GB 33.5 units 16 cores 1680 GB* for the price you specified?

Comment: Anatoly - I need 5 VMs for failover and redundancy if using EC2 - this is not the question I am trying to answer. Thanks for your insight. It is off topic.

Comment: http://traverstodd.com/creating-website-redirect-locations-for-s3-with-node-js-and-the-aws-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) copies metadata when using the [`aws s3 cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command.

**Update:** While metadata prefixed with `x-amz-meta-` is copied with the object, it appears that `Website Redirect Location` metadata is *not* copied.

Comment: John, I installed and configured aws-cli. I can not seem to save the metadata when copying or replacing. Can you share specific directives that have worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing this in node. easy peasy.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var config = {
    region: 'us-west-2'
};
AWS.config.update(config);

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.putObject ({
    Bucket: "myBucket",
    Key: "dir/index.html",
    WebsiteRedirectLocation: "http://io9.com/"
},
function(err,data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrote a more complete answer at http://traverstodd.com/blog which includes consuming a json file.